# How to add box with rounded borders in a image using php?

Tags: php, image-processing

I'm using this code---

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg('031.jpg');

// Create some colors
$back = imagecolorallocate($im, 70, 70, 70);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 110, 150, 195);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 70, 120, 180, 60, $back);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Name';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'AGENCYB.TTF';

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 100, 100, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

But I want to add round corner to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this example [link](http://www.assemblysys.com/dataServices/php_roundedCorners.php)